# C++ - inputting and outputting multiple integers with io redirection

Tags: c++, while-loop, io, io-redirection

I'm new to C++ and writing a simple program that should take integers from a file as ints and output them formatted appropriately. The issue is that the program skips one of the values when outputting. eg (\n representing a new line) "51 123\n -10\n 153 111" would come out as "123\n -10\n 153\n 111\n 0". Also any tips or pointers for bettering my code would be great.
Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    size_t i;
    int n;
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    if (argc == 1) {
        while (cin >> n) {
            cin >> a;
            cin >> b;
            cin >> c;
            cin >> d; 
            cin >> e;
            cout << setw(10);
            cout << a << "\r\n";
            cout << setw(10);
            cout << b << "\r\n";
            cout << setw(10);
            cout << c << "\r\n";
            cout << setw(10);
            cout << d << "\r\n";
            cout << setw(10);
            cout << e;
        }
    } else if (strcmp(argv[1],"-x")==0) {
        /* not used yet */
    } else if (strcmp(argv[1],"-o")==0) {
        /* not used yet */
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have code to write `n` to `cout`.

Comment: @RSahu What do you mean by that?

Comment: You are reading a number into `n` using `while ( cin >> n )`. That number is not being written out to `cout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1:

You are reading a number into `n` using `while ( cin >> n )`. That number is not being written out to `cout`. That means, the first number is being read and discarded.

Problem 2:

The line `cin >> e;` does not really read anything into `e`. That's why you have `0` in the output.

Suggested Fix:

Read all the numbers in the conditional of the `while`.

```
while (cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e)
{
   cout << setw(10);
   cout << a << "\r\n";
   cout << setw(10);
   cout << b << "\r\n";
   cout << setw(10);
   cout << c << "\r\n";
   cout << setw(10);
   cout << d << "\r\n";
   cout << setw(10);
   cout << e;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, works and your answer led me to this: `while (cin >> n ) {
   
   if (n < 0) {cout << "-";} else {cout << "+";}
   cout << setw(10);  
   cout << abs(n) << "\r\n";
  }`

Comment: @Bobbis, glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You while loop condition : `while(cin >> n)` will try to store an integer in your variable n and return true if the `cin >> n` succeeded thus allowing you to go inside the loop. I don' really see the point of using a loop if all your data is in a file and your are not using an array/vector to iterate through the file to get the file. Using an array will be way effective e.g:

```
int values[NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS]; // if number of elements is known
std::vector<int> values;// Use vector otherwise
```

In any case remove your while loop condition as a well as the braces associated to it and your code should run as expected.